# How to import selected presentations from a folder?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How can I import a selected presentation from a particular folder?

Below are the code which I tried but it is importing all the presentations which are stored in a particular folder.

```
Sub Merge()
' After doing the merge, open presentation #1
' Then run this code:

    Dim sPath As String
    Dim cFileNames As New Collection
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim x As Long

    sPath = CurDir  ' by default
    If Right$(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"

    sPath = InputBox("Path to PPT files (ex: c:\my documents\", _
        "Where are the files?", sPath)
    If sPath = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    sTemp = Dir(sPath & "*.pptx")
    While sTemp <> ""
        With cFileNames
            .Add (sPath & sTemp)
        End With
        sTemp = Dir
    Wend

    If cFileNames.Count > 1 Then
        ' open the first file
        Presentations.Open (cFileNames(1))

        ' Insert the other files
        For x = 2 To cFileNames.Count
            Call ActivePresentation.Slides.InsertFromFile( _
                cFileNames(x), _
                ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

For example. I have 10 presentations in **XYZ folder** but want to import only four selected presentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Sub Merge()
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

    'Set path to current dirrectory
    sPath = CurDir
    If Right$(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"

    'Set File Picker dialog
    Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog(Type:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'Set initial path and view, set multiselect capability
    With dlgOpen
        .InitialFileName = sPath
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
        .AllowMultiSelect = True

        'If user click on OK, insert selected files after last slide of current presentation
        If .Show = -1 And .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            For x = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
                ActivePresentation.Slides.InsertFromFile .SelectedItems(x), ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
            Next
        Else
            'User Cancelled
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any chance to import presentation from SharePoint folder ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a SharePoint setup on which to test.

Comment: Ok No problem, thanks for your quick reply
If you find any reference for that, please do let me know.